# How to call Python library from Grails (Jython mentioned)?

Tags: python, grails, jython

Can Jython help here? Should I run Grails above Jython and if yes, how? Somehow I should be able to run Grails and Python script on same JVM. There are other possibilities like making REST service for Python script or some interprocess communication but lets not deal with those for now.

Answer (score 0):

Jython is a JSR223 scripting language, so you should be able to follow the usual methods. (http://www.jython.org/archive/22/userguide.html#embedding-jython)

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("python")
engine.eval("x = 2 + 2")
```

It might be a non-trivial thing to get your Jython and any libraries you want to use organized on your server, but if all you need is the language and the standard libraries, you should be able to just add it as a dependency in your buildfile - it is on Maven Central (`compile 'org.python:jython:2.7.1b3'`).

But keep in mind that many python libraries (i.e. ones that use compiled C-code) are not going to work with Jython.

So, you might need to instead use a native python installation and call it as a process (using `ProcessBuilder`, for example).  Groovy has some nice sugar for doing this sort of thing with strings.

```
Process process = "python mypython.py".execute()
```

An internet search for things like "groovy execute shell command" will yield lots of examples.  Depending on your deployment scenario, this could be tricky to set up and maintain.